# May iterator's operator * return by-value?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

So, I want to understand if it is allowed for const_iterator (i.e not mutable) to return by-value.

What I have found is that return type of `*r` should be `reference`(1) where `reference` is `iterator_traits<X>::reference`(2). Naming clearly suggest that it's usually should be reference type, but does it have to?

Are there any difference between different iterator categories in that aspect?

All my links to standard(see below) are to n3242(last c++11 draft, I believe), but I'am also interested to know the difference between the versions of c++ too, if any.

(1) 24.2.2.2
(2) 24.2.1.11

Comment: a `const_iterator` should return a `const &` so that you don't have expensive copy operations.

Comment: iterator for `vector<bool>` points to wrapper. so yes.

Comment: @NathanOliver, the point is not in copying but in returning the value that lies in iterator.

Comment: @NathanOliver: using `int` doesn't imply expensive copy operation over `const int &`...

Comment: @NathanOliver: The question is *must* it return a reference, not *should* it. And copying can be cheaper than dereferencing, in which case you might prefer to return by value.

Comment: @Jarod42 worth to be an answer, perhaps

Comment: @Jarod42: Although `vector<bool>` is somewhat controversial, mostly because it breaks this rule (and thereby breaks code that tries to test whether two iterators refer to the same object).

Comment: @RiaD: With language-lawyer tag, I let people with standard reference answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward and stronger iterators are supposed to have `reference` be an actual reference type ([forward.iterators]/p1):

> A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward
>   iterator if
>
> - [...]
> - if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`,
> - [...]

Input iterators can have non-reference `reference`s. `istreambuf_iterator<charT>::reference`, for example, is `charT`.

The standard is [contradictory](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2437) about what `reference` can be for output iterators. To quote the linked LWG issue, it "can and can't be `void`".

Note that the standard itself lies: as of N4140, `vector<bool>::iterator` is supposed to be a random access iterator, but doesn't even satisfy the forward iterator requirements because its `reference` needs to be a wrapper class and not an actual reference type.<sup>*</sup> Another [current proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4346.html) includes more lies (see `bounds_iterator`).

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> With the edits applied by [N4284](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4284.html), [vector.overview] no longer places any requirements on `vector<bool>::iterator` beyond those found in table 96 - which requires forward iterator or stronger, so the standard is still lying.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit mandate in the language specification that operator * should return anything in particular.

Obviously it's good practice to return a reference if operator * is being used as a dereference operator as it normally is.

Boost xpressive is an example of a widely adopted and well regarded template library that uses operator * to return an object that represents the operation of matching multiple similar terms zero or more times.

Documentation here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/xpressive.html